# How can I use calculated values by formula in a new column for other rows in new column in R?

Tags: r, dataset

I have one column, A, that I need to use it to make a new column:

```
DT<- data.table(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3), B=0)
```

In a new column, B, I want to use a formula to seperate every 1...9. So, the output will be like this:

```
A  B
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  1 
7  1
8  1
9  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  2 
5  2
6  2
7  2 
8  2 
9  2
1  3 
2  3
3  3
```

I did in Excel with the below formula:
= IF(A2=1,IF(A1>1,B1+1,B1),B1

I tried this formula in R with different methods, shift(), lag(), ...:

```
DT$B = ifelse(DT$A == 1, ifelse(shift(DT$A, 1L, type="lag")>1, 
              DT$B<- 1+shift(DT$B, 1L, type="lag"), 
              DT$B<-shift(DT$B, 1L, type="lag")),
              DT$B<-shift(DT$B, 1L, type="lag"))
```

The results for the above formula was:

```
    A  B
 1: 1 NA
 2: 2 NA
 3: 3 NA
 4: 4  1
 5: 5  1
 6: 6  1
 7: 7  1
 8: 8  1
 9: 9  1
10: 1  1
11: 2  1
12: 3  1
13: 4  1
14: 5  1
15: 6  1
16: 7  1
17: 8  1
18: 9  1
19: 1  1
20: 2  1
21: 3  1
    A  B
```

If I have more than one replicate for each number in A, I cannot use ceiling.
The replicates for each number can be different.

For example:
The replicates for each number in A is different but I need the below output in B.

```
A  B
1  1
1  1
1  1
2  1
2  1 
3  1
4  1
4  1 
5  1
6  1
7  1
8  1
8  1
8  1
9  1
9  1
9  1
1  2 
1  2
2  2 
2  2
2  2
3  2
4  2
5  2
6  2
7  2
8  2
8  2
8  2
9  2
1  3 
2  3
3  3
```

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `diff` with `cumsum` :

```
library(data.table)
DT[, B := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(A) < 0))]
DT

#    A B
# 1: 1 1
# 2: 2 1
# 3: 3 1
# 4: 4 1
# 5: 5 1
# 6: 6 1
# 7: 7 1
# 8: 8 1
# 9: 9 1
#10: 1 2
#11: 2 2
#12: 3 2
#13: 4 2
#14: 5 2
#15: 6 2
#16: 7 2
#17: 8 2
#18: 9 2
#19: 1 3
#20: 2 3
#21: 3 3
#    A B
```

This will increment the value in `B` when the current value is less than the previous value.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried with the second example and it didn't work. I mean if I have more than one replicate for each number.

Comment: @MiladBagheri What is your expected output for second example? Can you update your post for it?

Comment: The answer needed a small change to compare against 0 instead of 1. Can you check the updated answer?

Comment: That's Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
DT[, B:= ceiling(seq_len(.N) / 9)]
```